# android game development dilemma

Tags: game-design, android

I'm doing a android game project that has a character that can do basic movements like step, turn left, turn right, raise left arm etc. When combining those moves together, the character can do some complicated movements like a dance routine or so.

I'm banging my head to figure out what to do about the graphics. I can do a 3D model with animation then export it to the format of Bones library that displays the character movements. Like shows in this [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QP4LoJ-87vY&feature=BFa&list=HL1320627333&lf=mh_lolz). I wish to have different characters with different characteristics like height, clothes colour and such. However, that means I have to stock pile more 3D models that have different settings.

Alternatively, I can attempt to code from scratch that have bones system, meshes, skinning, animation. More control and flexibility but the appearance won't be as good as 3D model and it takes alot more afford (as it appears to me). The character will be in 2D if I go down this route. I will use Android OpenGL library for this.

I thought of 2D but then I realize that it's pretty similar to 3D option.

My question is that what can I do here? What else I can do to make the best of this situation?

Edit: thanks for the comments and answer but I have sorted my "dilemma" now. Im using jpct-ae and bones library for my project. The downside is that I need to use a 3D model to make use of those library. They are actually very good and suitable for my need when working with a 3D model. Cheers.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Have you ever seen [4D boxing](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M4m0Y5EOPQo)? Simplistic characters, but because they did it all in their own code, they had greater control over movement. Characters could be shorter/taller, lighter/heavier, at least. These were very simple, untextured models, but it may have some bearing on your problem.

Comment: You should make the title of this question more about what your specific problem is (authoring animation data with multiple types of characters, I guess?).  It's too vague as is.

Comment: yes, you're right Tetrad! It was rather early in the morning so I didn't think too hard about the title...my bad.

Comment: @Nick: wow that is some old retro game, reminds me of 1995 console games. Good time. For my problem, I guess I will need to look into if it's possible for me to edit the character direction via an character editor or something.

Comment: How about using UDK? Its quite a learning curve, but gives some really good results.

Comment: Plz see my edit from op.

Comment: @bili If you found a solution, you should had it as an answer, to help future visitors who may have the same problem as you do.

Answer (score 1):

You could make ever changeable feature a model, nose 1 nose 2 hair 1 hair 2... have a list of textures that fit with every model, nose 1 color red texture, nose 1 blue texture... and have the models a different piece that moves on its own and animate the movement. Making 3D games and games for that matter takes time. To have a good game, you need a lot of effort. For example of what i'm talking about, look at Mount and Blade Warband, Sims 3, and Spore. (all computer games)

Comment: Plz see my edit from op.